# Spring bean not destroyed while redeploying app in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a webapp which is deploying on tomcat 9. As part of deployment, we just drop the war to the webapps directory and tomcat does the re-deployment of the war. But sometimes we see some error in the logs, basically destroy method of some spring bean is not invoked:

```
31-Aug-2017 21:41:35.292 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/globalsearch]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Aug 30 22:34:34 AEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Aug 30 22:34:26 AEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
WARN : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invocation of destroy method 'cleanUp' failed on bean with name 'GlobalSearchEventLoadMessageProcessing': java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/9.0.0.M19/webapps/globalsearch/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (No such file or directory)
WARN : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invocation of destroy method 'cleanUp' failed on bean with name 'globalSearchMessageSender': java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/9.0.0.M19/webapps/globalsearch/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (No such file or directory)
WARN : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invocation of destroy method 'stopServer' failed on bean with name 'globalSearchEmbeddedJMS': java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/9.0.0.M19/webapps/globalsearch/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (No such file or directory)
WARN : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'connectionFactory': java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/9.0.0.M19/webapps/globalsearch/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (No such file or directory)
```

The spring bean is creating a thread which is being destroyed in the destroy method and due to the error this Thread is still active even after re-deploy.

I am using xml file for the spring config:

```
<bean id="GlobalSearchEventLoadMessageProcessing"
    class="xxx.GlobalSearchEventLoadMessageProcessing"
    init-method="initialize" destroy-method="cleanUp">
</bean>
```

How to ensure that destroy method is called and executed completely.
I am using Java 8, Tomcat 9 and Spring 4.1.9

PS: I cant stop and start server for deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, the method WAS invoked:

```
WARN : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invocation of destroy method 'cleanUp' failed on bean with name 'GlobalSearchEventLoadMessageProcessing': java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/9.0.0.M19/webapps/globalsearch/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (No such file or directory)
```

But it failed, because most likely due to a race condition - you are trying to run some code from a `jar` file which was already removed from the container. Can you avoid using external libraries in your `cleanup` method?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Actually in the cleanup method Executor service is being shutdown and JMSContext are being closed which might be internally using these 3rd party jars....I dont think I can avoid this...
Any other suggestion?

Comment: It may be related to the JMSContext you're using as I believe this is an indirect call and Java / Tomcat does not "see" the dependencies in different threads & allow the JARs to be removed from memory before the code has finished execution. You may try to change the code to use your dependencies explicitly instead.